# how to fix undefined factory error in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 7 and facing an error when I start-server
also, I'm trying to composer update but still error facing

```
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: factory in
> D:\fivrr\INK_real_state\config\database\factories\UserFactory.php on
> line 19
>
```

my userfactory.php file

```
<?php


/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This directory should contain each of the model factory definitions for
| your application. Factories provide a convenient way to generate new
| model instances for testing / seeding your application's database.
|
*/

$factory->define(\App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Factories have changed since Laravel 8

Comment: im using laravel 7

Comment: stil same error
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: factory in

Comment: You are using variable `$factory`. Where did it come from? Where is it defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Ensure that you have "classmap": [ "database/factories"]" under "autoload" key in composer.json and try composer dump-autoload in terminal